# Get X-CSRF-TOKEN in Angular 2

Tags: angular, token, csrf, primeng, x-xsrf-token

I use the standard way of using X-CSRF-TOKEN in Angular 2 like this in my app.module:

```
provide: XSRFStrategy, useValue: new CookieXSRFStrategy('CSRF-TOKEN', 'X-CSRF-TOKEN')
```

I am using "primeng" for file-upload. I need to set up the token by my self like this:

```
private onBeforeSend(event) {
     event.xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRF-TOKEN", tokenThatINeed);
}
```

I need that token that Angular2 has generated for me. I don't know how to access the token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get your token with the following code

```
document.cookie
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [HttpXsrfTokenExtractor](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpXsrfTokenExtractor) like this:

```js
export class MyComponent {

    constructor(csrfTokenExtractor: HttpXsrfTokenExtractor) {
        console.log(csrfTokenExtractor.getToken());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So, I had a similar issue, and used a 3rd party javascript library to solve the problem.  There are a few different ones, but I used [angular2-cookie](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-cookie).  Once you inject the Service into your Component its pretty straight forward.  Here's what my code ended up looking like:

```
import {CookieService} from "angular2-cookie/core";

@Component({
    selector: 'fileUpload',
    templateUrl: 'app/components/files/fileUpload.html',
    providers: [CookieService]

})

export class FileUploadComponent {
    uploadUrl:string;

    constructor(private propertyService:PropertyService,
                private cookieService:CookieService){

        this.uploadUrl = propertyService.getProperties().server_location + "/files/upload"
    }

    onBeforeSend(event:any){
        event.xhr.open("POST", this.uploadUrl, true);
        event.xhr.setRequestHeader("X-XSRF-TOKEN", this.cookieService.get("XSRF-TOKEN"));
    }
}
```